# Javascript: setInterval 'Resumes' instead of 'Reset' on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I am having a problem of resetting an elapsed time using setInterval function. The timer runs well when pressing start and stopping it by clicking a button. But when I click start button again the timer resumes instead of reset. Based on my research ,clearInterval would reset that but doesn't work.

Here's a sample of my code. https://jsfiddle.net/4165y1x4/16/

**HTML**

```
<button id="get_data">Fetch Data</button>
<button id="stop1">Stop</button>
<span id="run-time"></span>
<br>
```

**Javascript**

```
var start = new Date().getTime(),elapsed = '0.0';

var s , url,i=0, time;
$("#get_data").click(function() {
  s = setInterval(function() {
    $("#run-time").html(tym());

  }, 100);

});

$('#stop1').click(function() {
  clearInterval(s);
  time = null;
});


function tym() {
  $("#run-time").html('');
  time = new Date().getTime() - start;
  var min = (time / 1000 / 60) << 0;
  var sec = (time / 1000) % 60;

  if (sec < 10) {
    sec = '0' + sec;
  }

  return elapsed = 'Elapsed Time: ' + min + ':' + sec + ' (min:sec.mil).'
}
```

I hope someone could help. Best Regards!

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` will return `time-stamp` of current time whenever you resume the interval..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah at Rayon comment correctly, you have to restart the time again.[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hm0s921/)

```
var start,
    elapsed = '0.0';

var s , url,i=0, time;
$("#get_data").click(function() {
   start = new Date().getTime();
  s = setInterval(function() {
    $("#run-time").html(tym());

  }, 100);
  // getData();

});

$('#stop1').click(function() {
  clearInterval(s);
  time = null;
});


function tym() {
  $("#run-time").html('');
  time = new Date().getTime() - start;
  var min = (time / 1000 / 60) << 0;
  var sec = (time / 1000) % 60;

  if (sec < 10) {
    sec = '0' + sec;
  }

  return elapsed = 'Elapsed Time: ' + min + ':' + sec + ' (min:sec.mil).'
}
```